# How to exclude warmup time from JMeter summary?

Tags: performance, jmeter, warm-up

I have a simple JMeter throughput test that spawns 20 threads and each thread executes a simple SQL query against a database. I have set a ramp up time of 10 seconds and a total test time of 70 seconds.

When I execute the test in non-GUI mode I see the following summary output:

```
summary +      1 in   0.1s =    7.4/s Avg:   135 Min:   135 Max:   135 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
summary + 137501 in  28.5s = 4831.0/s Avg:     3 Min:     1 Max:   614 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 20 Started: 20 Finished: 0
summary = 137502 in    29s = 4796.9/s Avg:     3 Min:     1 Max:   614 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary + 171000 in    30s = 5703.8/s Avg:     3 Min:     1 Max:   519 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 20 Started: 20 Finished: 0
summary = 308502 in    59s = 5260.8/s Avg:     3 Min:     1 Max:   614 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +  61016 in  11.5s = 5309.0/s Avg:     3 Min:     1 Max:   518 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 20 Finished: 20
summary = 369518 in  70.1s = 5268.9/s Avg:     3 Min:     1 Max:   614 Err:     0 (0.00%)
```

As you can see that the throughput is low in the first 30 seconds but picks up later. I understand that this could be due to the threads starting and other system components warming up.

Is there a way I can exclude "X" seconds worth of starting numbers from the final calculation. I have used some custom performance tests where I always excluded the first "X" seconds until the system reached a steady state before measuring the output.

Is there anyway I can do that in JMeter?

Comment: Any feedback on answers ? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jmeter-plugins to generate graphs

- http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/GraphsGeneratorListener/

And fill in start offset field.

Read this for using generation:

- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/automatically-generating-nice-graphs-at-end-of-your-load-test-with-apache-jmeter-and-jmeter-plugins/

Comment: OK. This is good information to know. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

JMeter result file is basically CSV file having the following format:

> **timeStamp**,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,bytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency
>
> **1440671556283**,1799,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,1591,1,1,1798

where first column is sample start time (in milliseconds since [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time))

If you need to omit first 30 seconds add 30000 to the first sampler timestamp, locate the closest row and delete all the rows from 1st to that one.

**Option 2:**

You can use [Synchronizing Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) to ensure that load starts with 20 threads from the early beginning.

Comment: Yes. I could do that but I was wondering if there is an inbuilt option to do this. Thank you for the answer. I really appreciate your time.