# Jmeter tps adjustment

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, tps

Do we need to adjust Throughput given by jmeter, to find out the actual tps of the system

For eg : I am getting 100 tps for concurrent 250 users. This ran for 10 hrs. Can I come to a conclusion like my software can handle 100 transactions per second. Or else do I need to do some adjustment and need to get a value. Why i am asking this because when load started, system will take sometime to perform in adequate level (warm up time). If so how to do this. Please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

By default JMeter sends requests **as fast as it can**, the main factor which are affecting TPS rate are:

- number of threads (virtual users) - this you can define in [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
- your application response time - this is not something you can control

Ideally when you increase number of threads the number of TPS should increase by the same factor, i.e. if you have 250 users and getting 100 tps you should get 200 tps for 500 users. If this is not the case - these 500 users are beyond [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) and your application [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) is somewhere between 250 and 500 users (if not earlier).

With regards to "warm up" time - the recommended approach of conducting the load is doing it [**gradually**](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide), this way you will allow your application to get prepared to increasing load, warm up caches, let [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) compiler/optimizer to go their work, etc. Moreover this way you will be able to correlate the increasing load with increasing/decreasing throughput, response time, number of errors, etc. while having 250 users released at once doesn't tell the full story. See

Answer (score 0):

The system warmup period varies from one system to the other. Warm up period is where configurations are cached, different libraries are initialized (eg. Builder.init()) and other initial functions that usually don't happen for subsequent calls. If you study results of the load test, there is a slow period at the very beginning. For most systems, it could be as small as 5 to 10 minutes. These values could be even negligible if the test is as long as 10 hours. But then again, average calculation can be effected if the results give extremely low values at the start (it always depend on the jump from initial warming up period to normal operations).

As per jmeter configurations this thread may explain the configuration. [How to exclude warmup time from JMeter summary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237837/how-to-exclude-warmup-time-from-jmeter-summary)